# VirualBox SBS 2003 WS 2008 R2 migration possible?

Tags: migration

We have a temp linux machine. Inside it is Small business server 2003 running in VirtualBox. We now have a new server machine with Server 2008 R2. How do we migrate/transfer data/roles/settings to the new Server 2008 R2? I am not a linux guy. What is the least painful way to do it? Or, is there a way to do it at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you will also be running VirtualBox on the new machine, then exporting the appliance or copying/cloning the virtual volume will address the hypervisor transfer/transition piece.

If the intention is to transition from VirtualBox to Hyper-V, then the VirtualBox volume can be converted over to the VHD format (if it is not already in that format). The conversion should take place after uninstalling the VirtualBox utilities from the SBS virtual machine and Windows 2003 SP2 (or later) should also be installed for full/added Hyper-V functionality (mouse integration, NIC support, etc.).

In both cases, the actual virtual machine (SBS) may also need "adjustments" (system hardware drivers) if the server hardware platforms are drastically different.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. We will be running a real machine. No more vm stuff. I might have asked the question incorrectly: What I really want is set up new server 2008 r2 machine and have it take over as domain controller.

Comment: SBS is an integrated bundle which probably can not be readily unbundled. It's ability to "integrate" into a regular/enterprise Windows environment is also limited by design. If your intentions are to run the SBS alongside/across a Windows environment, then you need to carefully verify its abilities and limitations when doing so.

Comment: No, I do not plan to have SBS 2003 running alongside. The new server will be promoted as new DC. I am asking for a very brief step by step procedure, just to point me to the right direction.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555073